# Does the android OS only kill applications when memory is low or is CPU usage also considered?

Tags: android, memory-management, operating-system, android-lifecycle

When memory is low on an android device, the OS can and will begin to kill processes.  Processes "not in use" (background services, and older processes) are generally killed first.

Is this the only metric that the OS uses to kill processes though or does the OS also consider CPU or battery usage?  For example, imagine a system that is not low in memory but is maxing out the cpu.  In this situation, will the OS begin killing processes?  If so, will the OS begin to immediately kill processes or is there a delay?  For example, if I was maxing out the CPU I would want the OS to kill background processes to free up the CPU but I would not want it to begin to kill foreground processes immediately.  Instead, I would want the OS to wait a period of time before killing more important processes.  I don't know the answers to these questions and I find them quite interesting.  Especially since whenever I read about how the OS handles app management usually only memory considerations are discussed.

Answer (score 1):

if process and Memory management need resources for system OS (android) background processes then OS will kill foreground processes immediately otherwise it will wait for internal response timeout event.

Answer (score 1):

Internally Linux allocate memory in form of pages from buddy system. When memory is not available OS enters to out of memory state and its select a process based upon certain alhortihm and kills that process and release the resources of that particular process.in case of Android has low memory killer driver which will get trigger depending upon Android oom adjective set by its configuration.
It does not check any cpu usages for killing application.